# How to display the current info base on date

Tags: sql, join, db2, subquery

My SQL script is to display the company, employee number, last name, first name, current job, and current salary.

To arrive at the current something implies there are dates involved.

How do I display the current job and salary of that employee?

emp (base table)

| empno | lastname | firstname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | james | lebron |
| 222 | bryant | kobe |
| 333 | jordan | michael |
| 444 | curry | stephen |

dept_job view

| company | empno | effdate | job | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lakers | 111 | 04/16/15 | assistant | 1500.00 |
| lakers | 111 | 02/02/16 | coach | 4000.00 |
| lakers | 222 | 07/22/17 | analyst | 3000.00 |
| bulls | 333 | 04/12/17 | secretary | 5000.00 |
| bulls | 333 | 07/28/18 | manager | 5000.00 |
| warriors | 444 | 10/04/19 | chef | 2000.00 |

I used MAX() on the effectivity date (effdate) to get the most current job and salary. But it displays past job and salary.

```
SELECT z.company, em.empno, em.lastname, em.firstname, z.job, z.salary
FROM emp em
JOIN ( SELECT dj.company, dj.empno, dj.effdate, dj.job, dj.salary
    FROM dept_job dj
    JOIN (SELECT company, empno, MAX(effdate) AS maxefffdate
        FROM dept_job
        GROUP BY company, empno) pe
    ON dj.empno = pc.empno AND dj.effdate = pe.maxeffdate) z
ON em.empno = z.empno
ORDER BY company, empno;
```

Result (wrong)

| company | empno | lastname | firstname | job | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lakers | 111 | james | lebron | assistant | 1500.00 |
| lakers | 111 | james | lebron | coach | 4000.00 |
| lakers | 222 | bryant | kobe | analyst | 3000.00 |
| bulls | 333 | jordan | michael | secretary | 5000.00 |
| bulls | 333 | jordan | michael | manager | 5000.00 |
| warriors | 444 | curry | stephen | chef | 2000.00 |

What I want

| company | empno | lastname | firstname | job | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lakers | 111 | james | lebron | coach | 4000.00 |
| lakers | 222 | bryant | kobe | analyst | 3000.00 |
| bulls | 333 | jordan | michael | manager | 5000.00 |
| warriors | 444 | curry | stephen | chef | 2000.00 |

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. PS Basic questions are faqs. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. Please read the edit ? help & advanced help. Indent code reasonably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dj.company
    ,em.empno
    ,em.lastname
    ,em.firstname
    ,dj.job
    ,dj.salary
FROM emp em
JOIN dept_job dj ON em.empno = dj.empno
JOIN (
    SELECT empno
        ,MAX(effdate) AS maxefffdate
    FROM dept_job
    GROUP BY empno
    ) z
ON dj.empno = z.empno
    AND dj.effdate = z.maxefffdate
ORDER BY company
    ,empno;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT z.company, em.empno, em.lastname, em.firstname, z.job, z.salary
FROM emp em
JOIN (
    SELECT dj.company, dj.empno,
        MAX(dj.effdate) OVER (
            PARTITION BY dj.company, dj.empno, dj.job, dj.salary
            ) AS maxeffdate,
        dj.job, dj.salary
    FROM dept_job dj ) z
ON em.empno = z.empno
ORDER BY company, empno;
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but sadly it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect in your WHERE clause which returns just the latest date and therefore gives you only the latest record.

```
SELECT dj.company, e.empno, e.lastname, e.firstname, dj.job
FROM emp e
JOIN dept_job dj ON e.empno = dj.empno
WHERE dj.effdate = (
  SELECT MAX(effdate)
  FROM dept_job
  WHERE empno = e.empno
)
ORDER BY e.empno;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**